# Scale ragdoll character after collision in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, ragdoll

I have a 3D ragdoll character and it collects coin like objects in game. I want to re-scale this character onTriggerEnter(). After scaling character, the character joint component is not updating therefore it looks like glitchy.
I added script to "Player" gameobject in a game and I'm trying to re-scale "Player" gameobject's localScale and also tried in "Bone" gameobject

- Here is my hierarchy:
- [image: hierarchy-screenshot]
- This is my script:
- [image: scale-script]
- **My question**: Is there any alternative way to scale my character through script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time I found the solution, the problem was with CharacterJoint component. It works only on start and not updating when you did change on Character, So I cached CharacterJoint's anchor values and I updated it on every change. Something like this, also [many thanks for Richard](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1311634/joint-system-scale-problems.html)

- [What I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZLs3.png)